# Conditional Formatting using the value of a cell and a text string from another

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

What I would like to do is format a range of cells based on whether their value is below a certain threshold (100%). However, I only want this to apply if a specific cell in that row has a specific string of text.

Basically, if A1 has "Joe - T" and A2 has "Sally", I want to type 90% into B1 and have it formatted (lets say it will be bolded and italicized). However, I do not want this to occur if I type the same number into B2. Basically, I want to format the cell if it is <100% but only if there is the string " - T".

I have tried `=AND(A1:33=" - T",B1:B33<100%)` and some variations on that to no avail.

I do not know how to properly display a table, forgive me I am brand new. Thank you

```
  A        B
1 Joe - T  ***90%***

2 Sally    90%
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
=AND(B1<1,IFERROR(FIND(" - T",A1),0)>0)
```

It checks if B1 is smaller than 100% (1) and if the string in A1 contains " - T"

Use this formula for formatting cel B1. Then copy down (formatting only)